# avoid repeat db search after redirect on django

Tags: python, django

I have a search box in my nav bar which sends queries to a view called `search`.  In `search` I check the DB to see if the search thing exists and redirect to `/thing/name` if it does:

```
def search(request):
    try:
        search_string = request.GET['q']
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        raise Http404

    try:
        Thing.objects.get(name=search_string)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thing/{}'.format(search_string))
    except Thing.DoesNotExist:
        # do something else...
```

In my `thing` view, I then want to display some information about the thing, requiring exactly the same DB lookup:

```
def thing(request, name):
    thing= Thing.objects.get(name=name)
    # do something with thing...
```

My question is, how can I perform the redirect, without having to do the same DB lookup?  Can I cache the lookup somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you would get much of a performance boost by doing this, the reason being that in one way or another you are going to be reading the result from the hard drive on the second page. Whether this takes the form of pulling from the db again or reading from a cache, the read still needs to take place. A workaround could be to check for the existence of the search term without pulling the full db row in the first view. You can do this by performing a count()

```
def search(request):
    try:
        search_string = request.GET['q']
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        raise Http404

    if Thing.objects.filter(name=search_string).count() == 1:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thing/{}'.format(search_string))
    else:
        # Thing doesn't exist, or there are multiple entries for Thing
```

This also means that any searches which return multiple results are handled, which your original code isn't doing.

Comment: thanks, I don't yet have any intuition as to how long this sort of thing takes.  Even for a lookup on a huge DB, will this take a similar amount of time to simply reading a value from disc?

Comment: @Ferguzz I haven't tested or compared the two so I don't know.  What I DO know is that grabbing the count in the search view is faster than the get() would be. Another thing I'd do is make sure the `name` field is indexed by the database (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index)